How are let assignments within view body handled in SwiftUI?
In SwiftUI, if we have a let that is declared inside the View body code such as:
var body: some View {

    // ...

    let arbitraryView = ZStack{
                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width:buttonCircleSide/2,height:buttonCircleSide/2)
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    }.frame(width: buttonCircleSide, height: buttonCircleSide)

    // ...
    HStack { 
        arbitraryView
    }
}

Is that optimized somehow either by the compiler or something else so that this object creation doesn't actually happen every time the view is refreshed?  Or do we need to move it higher in scope?  Is it not actually a "real" assignment operation where a memory allocation actually happens at runtime whenever “let blah =“ is encountered in the view body?

SwiftUI views are structs, which are value types. They are recreated when they are refreshed.  So yes, the creation happens every time the view is refreshed because the view that your let is enclosed in is recreated when it is refreshed. It is a "real" assignment operation

also, storing a view in a variable is not typical practice. You would typically just inline the view where it was needed.

But if it were re-used a lot (only inside this one view body), its worth doing it this way and not factoring it out into its own global struct.  I also wonder if the compiler would "unroll" the view body before compilation thus making the let statement "not real."  Also I know that "normal" sequential logical code doesn't work in views bodies like var temp = Int? if (something) temp = 4 does not work.  which tells me that view bodies are static/stateless and not recreated per se.  Also I'm pretty sure that let number = 5 would be factored out and allocate once. Sorry I'm extra foggy obviously.

No. You can't reliably say something like HStack { SettingsBar settingsBar }. And it wouldn't work as a global struct either. Simply abstract it to something like struct SettingsBarView:View { var imageName:String ...} and call it as SettingsBarView(imageName:"gear") as required

And you can't compare the optimisation or implementation of a literal, such as 5 whose value is known at compile time with a constant assignment of a struct that needs to be initialised.

Doing Image(systemName: "gear") just creates a struct value on the memory stack, it is negligible to create these values multiple times. You are right that SwiftUI does to an optimization, i.e. after the first time the Image value is init, it will init a UIImageView object once. If the Image value is init again nothing will happen. If Image is init with a different systemName param, it will update the UIImageView object with the new image. Lastly, if Image is not init, e.g. as part of an if clause within body that no longer passes, then the UIImageView object will be deinit and its memory freed up.
You can think of SwiftUI View structs like view model data descriptions for how UI objects should be init, update and deinit. It chooses the most suitable UI objects for the current context and platform.

Whether the view needs to be redrawn or not is checked by swiftUI runtime and that can depend on multiple things like position change or change in any of the view dependencies or changes in property wrapper values like @State or @ObservedObject etc
